# Django to Android

Tags: android, python, django, android-studio, apk

I have a web application set-up with Django (Python), and I want to convert it to an Android app (**.apk**).

Question 1 : Can I use Django (with some extra-packages) to create the **.apk**

Question 2 : Do I have to use Android Studio ? (I'm using Atom as a Text Editor).

Answer (score 1):

No you cant. Django is a web framework not a kit to develop android applications